# Java; Two-dimensional array lengths

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

OK so my question goes, if I can somehow manipulate lengths of both dimensions of my array using array.length.
For example what I want to do is check if my twodimensional array is quadratic and if not write out an exception.

Answer (score 2):

If by "manipulating" you mean getting the lengths, then yes. If you mean modifying, then no.

```
int[][] array = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```